# libcurl http post send data to server

Tags: c++, c, libcurl, intel-edison

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "127.0.0.1:8081/get.php");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"pulse=70 & temp=35" );
```

this above code run successfully but when I pass this

```
int pulsedata = 70;
int tempdata  = 35;

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "pulse=pulsedata & temp = tempdata");
```

when I run this above line it give me error
how can I pass this pulsedata and tempdata ??

Comment: Use a `std::ostream` to build the query URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible C solution:

```
char sendbuffer[100];
snprintf(sendbuffer, sizeof(sendbuffer), "pulse=%d&temp=%d", pulsedate, tempdata);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, sendbuffer);
```

Comment: eclipse give me warning   
format '%d' expects a matching 'int' argument [-Wformat=]

Comment: @parth9966 there was an extra `"` in my answer. I edited the answer and now it's correct. Try again.

Comment: i am pass pulsedata=70 but in database enter pulsedata = 1553236

Comment: @parth9966 and please show the declaration of `pulsedata` and `tempdata`.

Comment: sorry my mistake your code is working thanks michael

Comment: one more thing i want to ask you michale in this libcurl http post code run after it logout form the program how can i stop it and run continue ?

Comment: @parth9966 please ask another question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variable in strings like that, you have to format the string.

A possible C++ solution might be to use `std::ostringstream` like this:

```
std::ostringstream os;
os << "pulse=" << pulsedata << "&temp=" << tempdata;
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, os.str().c_sr());
```

With this solution, the `std::ostringstream` object (`os` in my example) needs to be alive until the CURL calls are all done.

---

Also note that the query-string I construct does not contain any spaces.